# How to map from a tuple without specifying each member field?

Tags: c#, automapper

Given the following sample classes

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FieldFromUser { get; set; }
}

public class Todo
{
    public string Title { get; set; } // !! map this one to UsernameWithTodoTitle.TodoTitle !!
    public string FieldFromTodo { get; set; }
}

public class UsernameWithTodoTitle
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string TodoTitle { get; set; } // !! this field represents Todo.Title !!
    public string FieldFromUser { get; set; }
    public string FieldFromTodo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map a user and a todo to `UsernameWithTodoTitle`. To solve this I'm using the packages

> AutoMapper v10.1.1

> AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection v8.1.1

When dealing with multiple sources this solution works fine for me:

```
public class UsernameWithTodoTitleMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public UsernameWithTodoTitleMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<(User, Todo), UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.Username,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Item1.Username))
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.TodoTitle,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Item2.Title))
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.FieldFromUser,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Item1.FieldFromUser))
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.FieldFromTodo,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Item2.FieldFromTodo));
    }
}
```

So I could map a user and a todo like so

```
var usernameWithTodoTitle = _mapper.Map<UsernameWithTodoTitle>((user, todo));
```

Since I'm using a tuple I have to specify each field because obviously Automapper can't know where to search for these fields when dealing with a tuple. The only different field names are `Todo.Title` and `UsernameWithTodoTitle.TodoTitle`. I would like to know if I can simplify the mapping profile, maybe I don't even have to use a tuple? The following profile is just a pseudo implementation what I would like to achieve

```
public class UsernameWithTodoTitleMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public UsernameWithTodoTitleMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<(User, Todo), UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
            // map all fields by name as expected and ...
            .ForMember(
                destination => destination.TodoTitle,
                memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Item2.Title));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply not use a tuple and create a class? Seems easier than to waste time/energy and stick to tuple.

Comment: This seems like an attempt to solve your problem: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5246899/A-Generic-Mapper-with-Value-Tuples-and-Generic-Tes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already mention, you don't need to use a `Tuple` - *see the update below if you really do*.
You can map a single target object from multiple sources.

Set up regular mappings from your sources `User` and `Todo` to the `UsernameWithTodoTitle` target.

```
CreateMap<User, UsernameWithTodoTitle>()

CreateMap<Todo, UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.TodoTitle,
        memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Title)
    );
```

To instantiate an `UsernameWithTodoTitle` object, apply one of both mappings; here from `User`.

```
var usernameWithTodoTitle = _mapper.Map<UsernameWithTodoTitle>(user);
```

Secondly, you update the newly created `UsernameWithTodoTitle` by applying the next mapping; here from `Todo`.

```
_mapper.Map(todo, usernameWithTodoTitle);
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you really want/need that `Tuple` mapping, such one can be set up as below, via an `IncludeMembers` rule upon the `Tuple` parts which will trigger the corresponding mappings.
This makes that the separate mapping rules from above are still required.

```
CreateMap<(User, Todo), UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
    .IncludeMembers(o => o.Item1, o => o.Item2);
```

You might prefer named `Tuple` parts.

```
CreateMap<(User User, Todo Todo), UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
    .IncludeMembers(o => o.User, o => o.Todo);
```

Complete example:

```
CreateMap<User, UsernameWithTodoTitle>();

CreateMap<Todo, UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
    .ForMember(
        destination => destination.TodoTitle,
        memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(source => source.Title)
    );          

CreateMap<(User User, Todo Todo), UsernameWithTodoTitle>()
    .IncludeMembers(o => o.User, o => o.Todo);

var user = new User { Username = "alfki" };
var todo = new Todo { Title = "work" };
var usernameWithTodoTitle = _mapper.Map<UsernameWithTodoTitle>((user, todo));

Console.WriteLine(usernameWithTodoTitle.Username); // alfki
Console.WriteLine(usernameWithTodoTitle.TodoTitle); // work
```